# How to map 3 arrays or more at same time

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

What is best way or best practice to map 3 or more arrays at the same time?

for this example:

At first I filter data by team name then map through them for showing them

(In this example I want use the `<div key={index} className={styles.member}> .... </div>`  **just one time** for coding less because they are totaly same)

--Yoe are free to change filter or map method in codes--

```
function MyApp() {
  const managementTeam = members.filter((m) => m.team === "management");
  const developmentTeam = members.filter((m) => m.team === "development");
  const uxTeam = members.filter((m) => m.team === "UX");
  const contentTeam = members.filter((m) => m.team === "content");

  const development = developmentTeam.map((m, index) => (
    <div key={index} className={styles.member}>
      <figure>
        <img className="image-cover" src={m.image} alt={m.faName} />
      </figure>
      <div className={styles.info}>
        <h3>{m.faName}</h3>
        <div className={styles.titleWrapper}>
          <div
            className={styles.snackItem}
            style={{ backgroundColor: m.background }}>
            {m.position}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));

  const management = managementTeam.map((m, index) => (
    <div key={index} className={styles.member}>
      <figure>
        <img className="image-cover" src={m.image} alt={m.faName} />
      </figure>
      <div className={styles.info}>
        <h3>{m.faName}</h3>
        <div className={styles.titleWrapper}>
          <div
            className={styles.snackItem}
            style={{ backgroundColor: m.background }}>
            {m.position}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));

  const ux = uxTeam.map((m, index) => (
    <div key={index} className={styles.member}>
      <figure>
        <img className="image-cover" src={m.image} alt={m.faName} />
      </figure>
      <div className={styles.info}>
        <h3>{m.faName}</h3>
        <div className={styles.titleWrapper}>
          <div
            className={styles.snackItem}
            style={{ backgroundColor: m.background }}>
            {m.position}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));

  const content = contentTeam.map((m, index) => (
    <div key={index} className={styles.member}>
      <figure>
        <img className="image-cover" src={m.image} alt={m.faName} />
      </figure>
      <div className={styles.info}>
        <h3>{m.faName}</h3>
        <div className={styles.titleWrapper}>
          <div
            className={styles.snackItem}
            style={{ backgroundColor: m.background }}>
            {m.position}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.membersWrapper}>
          <div>{management}</div>
          <div>{development}</div>
          <div>{ux}</div>
          <div>{content}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: concat all arrays in one array before mapping?

Comment: You can chain `arr.filter(/* ... */).map(/* ... */)`. Otherwise, that's a lot of duplicated JSX. Looks like you need a `TeamMember` component.

Comment: @PierreJanineh good but need map method 2 or 3 times!

Comment: @jsejcksn yes, I can create new component. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A lot of these answers are good and clear, but I don't like that they all use multiple iterations over the array when you can do it all in one sweep, with reduce. Example:

```
const Team = ({ image, faName, background, position }) => (
  <div className={styles.member}>
    <figure>
      <img className="image-cover" src={image} alt={faName} />
    </figure>
    <div className={styles.info}>
      <h3>{faName}</h3>
      <div className={styles.titleWrapper}>
        <div
          className={styles.snackItem}
          style={{ backgroundColor: background }}
        >
          {position}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default function App() {
  const teams = members.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
    const team = current.team;
    const content = <Team key={index} {...current} />;

    if (team in acc) {
      acc[team].push(content);
    } else {
      acc[team] = [content];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

  console.log(teams);

  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.membersWrapper}>
        <div>{teams.management}</div>
        <div>{teams.development}</div>
        <div>{teams.ux}</div>
        <div>{teams.content}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you need to make every team different and can't use one component then you could just create individual components and use switch statement instead of `if (team in acc)`  or you could use object and key-value pairs.

Comment: It is a good solution. I will replace the return with the below codes as well. I think it is more easy to maintain if there is a new team in the data in the future. what you need to do just add a new item in teamNames array.  ```const teamNames = ["management", "development", "UX", "content"];

return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.membersWrapper}>
            teamNames.map(name => <div>teams[name]</div>);
        </div>
    </div>
);```

Answer (score 0):

Make a array that contains the three arrays:

```
const arr = [ [ /* first array */ ], [ /* second array */ ], [ /* third array */ ] ]
arr.forEach(x=>{
    x.map( /* map content for each array */ )
}
```

Comment: Good but instead of forEach i use again map method because forEach return undefined!! also this way Need map method 2  times! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this below.

Note: It is not a performant solution as it loop through the members array for each teams items. Only good for small size of data.

```js
function MyApp() {
    const component = team =>
        members
            .filter(m => m.team === team)
            .map((m, index) => (
                <div key={index} className={styles.member}>
                    <figure>
                        <img
                            className="image-cover"
                            src={m.image}
                            alt={m.faName}
                        />
                    </figure>
                    <div className={styles.info}>
                        <h3>{m.faName}</h3>
                        <div className={styles.titleWrapper}>
                            <div
                                className={styles.snackItem}
                                style={{ backgroundColor: m.background }}
                            >
                                {m.position}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ));

    const teams = ["management", "development", "UX", "content"];

    return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <div className={styles.membersWrapper}>{teams.map(component)}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Nice Way. Thanks